# PHP - Custom message based on email receiver

Tags: php

I send an email with PHP to one service (Tumblr) and 2 other services via BCC. (Flickr and Posterous)
I send a title, message and tags. Now I would like to send just a title to Tumblr, a title and message to Flickr and a title, message and tags to Posterous.
Is that possible?

Comment: Anything is possible if you believe in yourself.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Right. Believe in yourself and tell me what is the original string that I hashed (with SHA-1) into this: `ec9a92b323fd4da56adfd8f60385a52ec155fdbb` ;o) (this is Applied Math, not Applied Psychology. Some things *are* impossible here, and that's a Good Thing.)

Answer (score 0):

> Now I would like to send just a title to Tumblr, a title and message to Flickr and a title, message and tags to Posterous. Is that possible?

Not using BCC as far as I know. You'd have to send three separate messages.

Comment: @Uli you can send any number of messages from the same PHPMailer instance, that's not a problem.